# Convert nested brackets from TextStructure[x,"DependencyStrings"]

Tags: string-manipulation

I feel this should be relatively straightforward, if I run the code:

```
TextStructure["I read the book he wrote.", "DependencyStrings"]
```

I get as string:

```
    {"(read, 2)((nsubj, (I, 1)), (dobj, (book, 4)((det, (the, 3)), 
(rcmod, (wrote, 6)((nsubj, (he, 5)))))))"}
```

I want to convert this into a nested list I can index.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version are you running? On V12 I get `{"(read, 2)((nsubj, (I, 1)), (dobj, (book, 4)((det, (the, 3)), 
(rcmod, (wrote, 6)((nsubj, (he, 5)))))))"}`

Comment: Looks like lazy unfinished functionality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
str = TextStructure["I read the book he wrote.", "DependencyStrings"];
```

> {"(read, 2)((nsubj, (I, 1)), (dobj, (book, 4)((det, (the, 3)), 
>   (rcmod, (wrote, 6)((nsubj, (he, 5)))))))"}

```
ToExpression @ 
   StringReplace["{" <> str[[1]] <> "}", {")(" -> "}, {", "(" -> "{", ")" -> "}"}]
```

> {{read, 2}, {{nsubj, {I, 1}}, {dobj, {book, 
>           4}, {{det, {the, 3}}, {rcmod, {wrote, 6}, {{nsubj, {he, 5}}}}}}}}